# Set different header using docx factory

Tags: docx

I am evaluating docxfactory api and it has good features. I was trying to add header and footer to the docx template and it worked fine. However, I want different header and footer for each page. For example, I need to show customer name in the header and customer address in the footer section for each customer. The body of the page will have other customer order. Each customer has to starts in new page. I tried the below sample, but the header was same for all customer. The header didnt change. I tried adding section break to the document, but it didnt work. I searched the docx factory forum, but couldn't find it. Not sure if this is the right place.

```html
public class Dp1 {
 public static void main(String argv[]) {
  docpaging();
 }
 
  public static  void docpaging() {
    String inputFile = "D:\\fields.docx";
    String compileFile = "D:\\fields.dfw";
    String outputFile = "D:\\fields_output.docx";
    
    
    try {
      WordProcessingCompiler.compile(inputFile, compileFile);
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      WordProcessingMerger.load(compileFile);
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        WordProcessingMerger.setClipboardValue("_Header", "PrintDate", (double) j);
        WordProcessingMerger.paste("Account");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          WordProcessingMerger.setClipboardValue("Line", "LineDate", new Date());
          WordProcessingMerger.setClipboardValue("Line", "LineAmt", (double) i);
          WordProcessingMerger.setClipboardValue("Line", "LineDesc", "Desc" + i);
          WordProcessingMerger.paste("Line");
        }
      }
      WordProcessingMerger.save(outputFile);

      System.out.println("Completed (in " + (double) (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000 + " seconds).");
      openFile(outputFile, false);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I am unable to attach the docx sample. It can download from docxfactory.com. The template screenshot is given below. I am trying to replace the placeholder PrintDate in the header with different values, but it always shows the first value. Even, I tried adding the page break in the document, it didn't work.

Thanks. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that docxfactory works, at the moment, is it creates a new section (with a different header and footer) if a different section is pasted. this is the only case that would force a new section, at the moment.

what can be done is if the fields in the _header or _footer are changed it would force a new section so those changes will be reflected. it is actually a small change. you're encouraged to make the change yourself on github or wait for me to do it :) if it's an urgent case, feel free to contact me directly.

for the time being, can you just put the details in the top and bottom of the page instead of using the section header and footer? have a look at the paging chapter for pages that expand to fill the page.

please join the project on github.

btw new word and excel version coming out soon with lots of new features.

disclosure, i wrote the project.

love,
alon

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently, we using other third-party APIs for various document generations. Some places we are placing the content on the document top and bottom instead of header and footer. We are in trying to move away from these and use some clean solutions. I found docx factory has some cool features for some our requirement. One of the requirement was having different header and footer which almost all of our reports need. Getting this feature will help us.

Comment: Do you have any estimate on the timeline when the new word/excel version hitting the market?

Comment: Probably, a month or two from now. BTW I'd really like to know which "third-party APIs for various document generations" you're using? If docxfactory had this small header and footer feature would that take care of all your generation requirements?

Comment: tools like jaspper, writing using word interops. we need features like template based generation, separate header footer for each page in the document, rendering html content inside tablecell, replace place holders in paragraph, inside table, show or hide sections inside a document based on conditions, have multiple tables which are populated at runtime, adjacent and nested tables. Some docs could go for about 1000 pages and hence performance is also of importance. Is it possible for you to rollout the separate header footer functionality? it would be great help. Thanks.